# Bulding java objects with nmcli result

Tags: java, linux, stream, ssid

In this follow code, i list all ssids wifi connection using nmcli (Ubuntu):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException
{
    ProcessBuilder contrutorProcessos = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "nmcli -e yes dev wifi");
    contrutorProcessos.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process processo = contrutorProcessos.start();
    BufferedReader leitorDados = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processo.getInputStream()));

    String linhaDado;

    while ((linhaDado = leitorDados.readLine()) != null)
            for (char letra : linhaDado.toCharArray())
                System.out.println((int) letra);
}
```

And i need to create one object with each SSID finded.

But this columns dont separate with a commas or other char. The columns are separate with spaces " " (32 decimal ASCII code). In this form, i can't create objects with strong security.

Can you help-me? NMCLI is a best form to do this?

Thank you!